# Run single JUnit test class multiple times with different instance variable values

Tags: maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a JUnit test class whose every method will do something different based on the value of a local flag variable.  Not that it matters too much but if the flag is true, the data gets saved in one format, if false it is saved in another, using a factory method to create an instance of the DAO object that is based on the flag.  What I would like to do is not write two sets of tests considering that I only need to flip one switch.

I am running this in Maven.  Is there a way to replicate the execution of this one test class while switching the value of the flag (using a setter?) between different test executions?

```
public class BifurcatedTest {

    private boolean formatFlag = false;

    @Test
    public void testGadgetOne(){
        Gadget gadg = new Gadget(1, "Gadget One");
        GadgetDAO gadgDAO = GadgetAccessFactory.getGadgetDAO(this.formatFlag);
        gadgDAO.save(gadg);
        assert(true);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGadgetTwo(){
        Gadget gadg = new Gadget(2, "Gadget Two");
        GadgetDAO gadgDAO = GadgetAccessFactory.getGadgetDAO(this.formatFlag);
        gadgDAO.save(gadg);
        assert(true);
    }

    public void setFormatFlag(boolean formatFlag) {
        this.formatFlag = formatFlag;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**  I understand I could use a [`Suite`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Suite.html) and inject the variable through the constructor and then list the class twice in the suite declaration.  But ideally, I would like to use an annotation something similar to

```
@MultiExec("formatFlag=true;formatFlag=false");
```

Before the class declaration and that Maven would understand that annotation and run it as many times and do the specified injection.

Comment: Rather than complicated the build, I think it would be better to write two sets of wrapper test methods that wrap the functions taking the flags.  One set would pass in one flag while the other set would pass in the other flag.  This would only add a couple lines of code per test method.

Comment: that would involve a lot of code invoking every method twice.  it would be more elegant to use a `Suite` and inject the variable through the constructor and then list the class twice (better than calling each method twice)

Comment: see the update i just posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your requirement was similar as DataProvider in TestNG.

Which you can do it in JUnit as [Writing Java tests with data providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203730/writing-java-tests-with-data-providers).