# How to prepare and provide test data

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, test-data

I am trying to write a test case (using Java, Maven, Junit, Eclipse) for small function that calculates difference of sum of diagonals of matrix.

**Function to be tested**

```
    public static int diagonalDifference(Integer matrix[][], int n) {
        int diagonalSum1 = 0;
        int diagonalSum2 = 0;
        int diagonalDifference = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            diagonalSum1 = diagonalSum1 + matrix[i][i];
            diagonalSum2 = diagonalSum2 + matrix[i][Math.abs(i - 2)];
        }

        diagonalDifference = Math.abs(diagonalSum1 - diagonalSum2);
        return diagonalDifference;
    }
}
```

From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19349565/7115684 i unsuccessfully tried to something like,

```
public class testSolutions {

    Solution solution = new Solution();

    Integer a[][] = { { 11, 2, 4 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 10, 8, -12 } };
    Integer b[][] = { { 12, 22, 8 }, { 2, 16, 8 }, { 10, 5, -1 } };

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] provideMatrixAndExpectedSum() {
         return new Object[][] { { a, new Integer(15) } };
    }

    @Test
    @UseDataProvider("provideMatrixAndExpectedSum")
    public void test(Integer a[][], int n) {

        int diagonalDifference = Solution.diagonalDifference(a, n);

        assertEquals(diagonalDifference, 15);
    }
}
```

when i run this, i get an error "Method test should have no parameters."

Here my questions are:

1. How can write test case for such situation ?
2. How can i prepare data for test ?
3. Can we create a file like properties kind of file in resource folder so that it can be provided to other function as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the function to be tested accepts a 2d array and returns an integer and you need to test whether the value returned is correct or not.
I have a similar code and test unit using JUint. Don't bother what my code does, only pay attention to what input is passed and the output to be validated.

```
public class countUniqueNums {

public int countUnique (int[] nums) {
    int unique=0;
    int [] intVal = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for (int i = 0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        intVal[nums[i]+9]++;
        if (intVal[nums[i]+9]==1)
            unique++;
        else
            if (intVal[nums[i]+9]==2)
                unique--;
    }
    return unique;
 }
}
```

And the test unit is as:

```
import static junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner.$;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;    
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;    
import junitparams.JUnitParamsRunner;
import junitparams.Parameters;

@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class countUniqueNumsParamTest {

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unused", "deprecation" })
    private static final Object[] countUniqueNumbers () {
        return $(
                // Parameters are (1,2),  1=expected result count, 2= input array
                    $(1,new int[]{0}),      //Test Case 1
                    $(0,new int[]{}),       //Test Case 2
                    $(0,new int[]{0,0}),    //Test Case 3           
                    $(0,new int[]{0,0,0}),  //Test Case 4

                    $(1,new int[]{0,1,1,1}),    //Test Case 5
                    $(1,new int[]{1,1,1,0}),    //Test Case 6
                    $(2,new int[]{1,0,2,1}),    //Test Case 7
                    $(4,new int[]{0,1,2,3})     //Test Case 8

                    );
    }
    @Test
    @Parameters(method="countUniqueNumbers")
    public void test(int unique, int[] nums) {
        countUniqueNums cun = new countUniqueNums();
        assertEquals(unique, cun.countUnique(nums));
    }
}
```

Make sure you are importing the correct libraries for JUnit in eclipse. Tailor your test case class to match mine and you should be good to go.
Hope this helps.

Comment: what is $ sign ?

Comment: The $ method is a static method that is an abbreviation for new Object[].
This approach has the advantage of providing a parameterized test without requiring the method under test to be static.
JUnitParamsRunner provides a more powerful way of parameterizing JUnit tests (here is the JUnit Test Class code without the imports)

You will also need to add Junit Params jar to your build path. Later add this to your java build path.

Answer (score 0):

I find that approach usually quite disturbing for use cases like yours, especially because it's not necessary and makes it much harder to read and understand the test.

Why is it not necessary? If I write a method that sums up two integers and I test 1 + 2 = 3, why would I need to write another test that ensures, that 2 + 2 = 4? The questions you can ask yourself is, "*what do I need to change in my code*, so that the second test (2+2=4) *fails*, *but* the first test still passes?" If I can change production code, so the second one fails, but the first one does not, that means it's usually two separate test.

Why is it harder to understand?
One block of

```
int summand1 = 1;
int summand2 = 2;

int sum = MyMath.sum(summand1, summand2);

assertEquals(3, sum);
```

is imo much easier to understand than

```
public void myTest(int summand1, int summand2, int expectedResult) {
   int sum = MyMath.sum(summand1, summand2);

   assertEquals(expectedResult, sum)
}
```

If the test fails, I have all the information within a few lines of code. For the second, you don't know what parameters were used, the definition of the parameters can be somewhere in your test class, so you use more time to actually find out what the problem is.