# Writing different test for different API keys

Tags: rest, api, testing, automated-tests, rest-assured

While automating rest API I came to know that there are different API keys for different versions of the application ( Web, Android and iOS). I want to know should I write tests for each API key? I am asking this because I am getting different results but the same fields for different API keys

Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: I don't think you have to write different tests for api keys. if web, android and ios use same rest api just write your tests for one valid api key. you can also add some scenarios for invalid/expired keys. this should be enough

Comment: Thanks, @bhusak for your advice. I have updated my question. I am getting different results for different API keys but JSON fields are the same. I don't understand why the question is negatively voted

Comment: Depending on your testing framework (TestNG, JUnit) you can use parametrized tests mechanism. But again since your responses will differ expected results will be different as well so data driven approach can help. For example, in TestNG you can use @DataProvider annotation. Take a look at this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/19349565/6168167