# Unit Test using Theories fail using multiple data and running the test at once

Tags: android

I'm trying to write a unit test using multiple data and the test should be run once and it should verify the test using different data. The error that it throws is:

java.lang.AssertionError: Never found parameters that satisfied method assumptions.  Violated assumptions: []

Below is the code I'm using:

```
@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class LoginTest {

@DataPoints
public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
    System.out.println("Creating data points");
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            {"umersaleem", ""}, {"umersaleem78@gmail.com", "Umar123"},
            {"umersaleem78@gmail.com", "umar123"}, {"umersaleem78@gmail.com", "Umar123@"}
    });
}

@Theory
public void validateLogin(String username,String password) {
    System.out.println("In validate login method");
    LoginUtil util = LoginUtil.INSTANCE;
    boolean result = util.validateLoginInput(username,password);
    assertThat(result).isTrue();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got Help from:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19203786/12085098

Resolved my issue using the below Solution:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class LoginTest {

private final String username,password;

public LoginTest(String username,String password){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            {"test@gmail.com", "test"}, {"text", "test"},
            {"test", "test"}, {"test@gmail.com", "Test123@"},{"test","test123@T"}
    });
}

@Test
public void validateLogin() {
    LoginUtil util = LoginUtil.INSTANCE;
    boolean result = util.validateLoginInput(username,password);
    assertThat(result).isTrue();
}
```

}