# In Java is there a way to pass an object reference into a method, instantiate it inside the method, and access it outside of the method?

Tags: java

I have JUnit test code ... here's a very simplified example of what it looks like ... something like this:

```
   public void test001() {
      String sValue = "abc123";

      Customer cust = buildCustomer();
      Invoice inv = buildInvoice(sValue);
      Account acc = buildAccount();

      doTestStuff(cust, inv, acc);
   }
```

I need to create lots of different test methods with different `sValue` values so I'd like to pass references to the objects into a common method and instantiate them inside the method.

Is that possible?  I'd like to do something like this ...

```
   private void doSetup(String sValue, Customer cust, Invoice inv, Account acc) {   
      cust = buildCustomer();
      inv = buildInvoice(sValue);
      acc = buildAccount();
   }

   public void test001() {
      Customer cust = null;
      Invoice inv = null;
      Account acc = null;
      doSetup("abc123", cust, inv, acc);
      doTestStuff(cust, inv, acc);
   }

   public void test002() {
      Customer cust = null;
      Invoice inv = null;
      Account acc = null;
      doSetup("qwerty", cust, inv, acc);
      doTestStuff(cust, inv, acc);
   }

   public void test002() {
      Customer cust = null;
      Invoice inv = null;
      Account acc = null;
      doSetup("lemonpie", cust, inv, acc);
      doTestStuff(cust, inv, acc);
   }
```

Comment: Probably not. You can't pass the object to the method without instantiating it.

Comment: What you have should work, roughly, when you pass all required arguments. (You seem to be on Unit3, and I'd  recommend upgrading.) What problems did you run into with that approach?

Comment: If you haven't instantiated it, there's nothing to pass.

Comment: And if you have already instantiated it, you've already instantiated it. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @Robert hi Robert, just FYI I modified my sample code so the object references are all internal to the testXXX() methods ... this illustrates what I'm trying to do better.

Comment: An object *is* an instance. Synonyms.

Comment: I think there is some confusion here. Your old code had member variables and you used a method to initialize them, which you called from your test methods. That works. Your current code has local variables. When you pass them to the setup method and that method asignes them to something else, the values at the caller's site are not changed, so that doesn't do what you want. You would have to return them from the setup method and since you can only return one thing, you'd have to wrap them in an object. Your call if that makes the code more or less readable.

Comment: Have a look at [Spock](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-spock). I wouldn't use anything else.

Comment: If your tests differ only with sValue and doTestStuff is same, why wouldn't you just use data provider? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203730/writing-java-tests-with-data-providers